# No HDMI option in sound playback devices

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I'm using an off-lease refurbished HP 6005 small form factor PC running Windows 7 with an integrated ATI HD 4200 GPU. The HD output port is displayport, so I bought an adapter to hook up to my TV. There is no option to change to any other audio output aside from "Speakers".

My drivers are all up-to-date. I installed them directly from the websites for my GPU and sound device (AMD updated 4/29/2013 and Realtek updated 5/5/2015).

I know it is not an issue with the adapter or the cable as they work with other devices.

edit: Looking at my BIOS I found that there is an ATI HD Audio option in advanced and an onboard sound option in security.

I disabled the onboard sound which disables all sound on my computer and also removes the ATI HD Audio option from the BIOS. I turned it back on, and my options on the ATI HD are IRQ 5, 10, and 11 as well as disable. This means that my PC can see the HD sound option through the GPU?

Comment: Right click in playback device lower pane and select "show disabled devices" and "show disconnected devices", does it show now?

Comment: I wish it were that simple @Moab :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for HDMI playback not showing.

1. Not proper drivers, did you make sure you downloaded HD Series Drivers? I had issues with the AMD site once because of that... ended up downloading legacy drivers. I would even recommend doing it manually. I took the info you provided and the site offered me 10/15/2013 drivers. Yours are older.
2. Maybe is not enabled or not being detected. Right-click Windows Mixer > Playback Devices > Click anywhere on the list of shown devices and make sure "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconnected Devices" are both checked.
   After that you should be able to see your HDMI Playback device, if it's shown as disconnected there may be a driver problem, if it is disabled, enable it so you can use it.

If even after those steps you can't still use HDMI as playback, you are lacking a driver or your GPU does not support it (which I will find it really weird). Hope I was helpful.

Comment: a 4200 will only have legacy drivers, it went unsupported in 2013. Catalyst 13.9 was the last version

Comment: Tetsujin is correct. Whenever I put in the specs on AMD's site it gives me Catalyst 13.9 and #2 I have both of them checked but Speakers is still the only option. Unless my device is faulty, the ATI HD 4200 does support audio through displayport. I can't figure out how to make it work though.

Answer (score 0):

My TV was not appearing as an audio playback device either, using Intel HD 4000. I fixed this in two steps:

1. Confirmed that the device was present in Windows Device Manager: "Intel(R) Display Audio". That then suggested a driver problem.
2. Inspected the device properties and used *Roll Back Driver* on the *Driver* tab.

The TV playback device appeared almost immediately in the list after that, without a reboot or even unplugging the HDMI cable.